# Modular arithmetic. How to solve the following equation?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to solve the following equation?

I am interested in the methods of solutions.

**n^3 mod P = (n+1)^3 mod P**

P- Prime number

**Short example** with the answer. 
Could you gives step-by-step solutions for my example.

**n^3 mod 61 = (n + 1)^3 mod 61**

Integer solutions:

n = 61 m + 4,

n = 61 m + 56,

m element Z

Z - is set of integers.

Comment: you should investigate the prime (or relative prime) factors of `n` and use some properties of modulo equations regarding relative prime numbers

Comment: Nikos M.  Could you give an example, for understanding what do you mean?

Comment: for example search for non-linear congruence equations, or start with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454767/solving-the-congruence-for-powers) aka fermat's little theorem

Answer (score 2):

An other way to state `n^3 ≡ (n+1)^3` is `n^3 ≡ n^3 + 3 n^2 + 3 n + 1` (just work out the cube of n+1) then the cubic terms cancel out to give a nicer quadratic `3 n^2 + 3 n + 1 ≡ 0`

Then the usual quadratic formula applies, though all of its operations are now modulo P, and the determinant is not always a quadratic residue in which case there are no solutions to the original equation (this happens about half the time). This involves finding a square root modulo a prime, which is not hard for a computer to do for example with the Tonelli–Shanks algorithm, though not trivial to implement.

By the way `3 n^2 + 3 n + 1 = 0` has the property that if `n` is a solution, then `-n - 1` is too.

For example, with some Python, once all the support functions exist it is pretty simple:

```
def solve(p):
  # solve 3 n^2 + 3 n + 1 ≡ 0
  D = -3 % p
  sqrtD = modular_sqrt(D, p)
  if sqrtD == 0:
    return None
  else:
    n = (sqrtD - 3) * inverse(6, p) % p
    return (n, -(n+1) % p)
```

Inverse modulo a prime is really easy,

```
def inverse(x, p):
  return pow(x, p - 2, p)
```

I adapted [this implementation of Tonelli-Shanks](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/07/computing-modular-square-roots-in-python) to Python3 (`//` instead of `/` for integer division)

```
def modular_sqrt(a, p):
    """ Find a quadratic residue (mod p) of 'a'. p
        must be an odd prime.

        Solve the congruence of the form:
            x^2 = a (mod p)
        And returns x. Note that p - x is also a root.

        0 is returned is no square root exists for
        these a and p.

        The Tonelli-Shanks algorithm is used (except
        for some simple cases in which the solution
        is known from an identity). This algorithm
        runs in polynomial time (unless the
        generalized Riemann hypothesis is false).
    """
    # Simple cases
    #
    if legendre_symbol(a, p) != 1:
        return 0
    elif a == 0:
        return 0
    elif p == 2:
        return 0
    elif p % 4 == 3:
        return pow(a, (p + 1) // 4, p)

    # Partition p-1 to s * 2^e for an odd s (i.e.
    # reduce all the powers of 2 from p-1)
    #
    s = p - 1
    e = 0
    while s % 2 == 0:
        s //= 2
        e += 1

    # Find some 'n' with a legendre symbol n|p = -1.
    # Shouldn't take long.
    #
    n = 2
    while legendre_symbol(n, p) != -1:
        n += 1

    # Here be dragons!
    # Read the paper "Square roots from 1; 24, 51,
    # 10 to Dan Shanks" by Ezra Brown for more
    # information
    #

    # x is a guess of the square root that gets better
    # with each iteration.
    # b is the "fudge factor" - by how much we're off
    # with the guess. The invariant x^2 = ab (mod p)
    # is maintained throughout the loop.
    # g is used for successive powers of n to update
    # both a and b
    # r is the exponent - decreases with each update
    #
    x = pow(a, (s + 1) // 2, p)
    b = pow(a, s, p)
    g = pow(n, s, p)
    r = e

    while True:
        t = b
        m = 0
        for m in range(r):
            if t == 1:
                break
            t = pow(t, 2, p)

        if m == 0:
            return x

        gs = pow(g, 2 ** (r - m - 1), p)
        g = (gs * gs) % p
        x = (x * gs) % p
        b = (b * g) % p
        r = m


def legendre_symbol(a, p):
    """ Compute the Legendre symbol a|p using
        Euler's criterion. p is a prime, a is
        relatively prime to p (if p divides
        a, then a|p = 0)

        Returns 1 if a has a square root modulo
        p, -1 otherwise.
    """
    ls = pow(a, (p - 1) // 2, p)
    return -1 if ls == p - 1 else ls
```

You can see some results on [ideone](https://ideone.com/6KttRn)

Comment: harold -  I am satisfied with your answer, this is really the shortest way to solve my example, thanks for your feedback.